# Unable to host IdentityServer4 code sample of ASP.NET Core as Windows Service

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have problem setting up the app from the link below as Windows service

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/master/Quickstarts/2_ResourceOwnerPasswords/src/IdentityServer

Whenever the first request is sent to the Windows Service, it is stopped, and the error is generated:

Error from ResourceOwnerClient:

`Error connecting to http://localhost:1234/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks: An error occurred while sending the request.`

Event log:

```
Application: IdentityServer.exe
CoreCLR Version: 4.6.27110.4
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException: 'overlapped' has already been freed.
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolBoundHandleOverlapped.CompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

The code below follows [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

```
    public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                WinServices(args);
            }
            public static void WinServices(string[] args)
            {
                var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));
                var builder = CreateWebHostBuilder(args.Where(arg => arg != "--console").ToArray());


                if (isService)
                {
                    var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
                    var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
                    //use a path to the app's published location instead of Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().
                    builder.UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot);
                }

                var host = builder.Build();

                if (isService)
                {
                    host.RunAsCustomService();
                }
                else
                {
                    host.Run();

                }
            }
            public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
            {
                return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                        .UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .UseUrls("http://localhost:1234")
                        .UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
                        {
                            configuration
                                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                                .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication", LogEventLevel.Information)
                                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                                .WriteTo.File(@"C:\Logs\\identityserver_log.txt")
                                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level}] {SourceContext}{NewLine}{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}", theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate);
                        });
            }
```

ASP.NET CORE 2.2

Please note that it works when lauched as self-hosted from visual studio.

Added `AddDeveloperSigningCredential()` to below to fix other issue.

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            Environment = environment;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // uncomment, if you wan to add an MVC-based UI
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
            }
            else
            {            

            }      
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            // uncomment if you want to support static files
            //app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseIdentityServer();           
            // uncomment, if you wan to add an MVC-based UI
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

**Settings on *.csproj file**

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**Build and Setup script:**

```
  dotnet publish --configuration Release --self-contained -r win-x64 --output C:\myApp              
sc create "SSO" binPath= "c:\myApp\IdentityServer.exe"
sc start "SSO"

sc stop "SSO"
sc delete "SSO"
```

**Update 2**

It turns out that the issue is caused when the Resource Owner Password client sends the request.
It works when Postman is used instead.
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/master/Quickstarts/2_ResourceOwnerPasswords/src/ResourceOwnerClient

Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean `AddDeveloperSigningCredential` resolve your issue?

Comment: please see update

Comment: please see update 2

Comment: @Pingpong Did you make any progress on this issue?  Have you tried under 3.0 or 3.1 yet?

Comment: no, didnt try it again.